# Where can I ask about Julia-code?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, site-recommendation

On which site can I ask about Julia code?

I found on GitHub a useful code written on Julia, and I need help running it on my Pc. Where can I ask questions related to this?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/julia/info)

Comment: *"I need help running it on my Pc"* - Potentially not here (the site or even the network). It'll depend on the exact question

Comment: @Nick So there is not a place for Julia on StackExchange?

Comment: There is, Stack Overflow (as _linked_ by Zoe), but it'll depend on the exact question.

Comment: To be clear, questions about programming in Julia are on-topic on Stack Overflow, but a question phrased "I need help running this Julia code" might not be well received. This is an opportunity to take the [tour] and revisit [ask].

Comment: A lot of technologies will have help with "how to get started". I usually just put that in a search engine and see what comes up. For Julia it got me [Julia in VS Code - Getting Started](https://www.julia-vscode.org/docs/stable/gettingstarted/)

Comment: If you [edit] the exact question you want to ask into your meta question here, we can tell you if it’s acceptable on any site in the network, and if it is, which one. There’s an outside chance someone will recommend you ask on a different, specific meta-site first, but given what you describe, i think that’s unlikely; I suspect your question is either off-topic or best placed on SO.

Comment: You can ask it on Julia Discourse https://discourse.julialang.org/c/first-steps/8

Comment: @Nick Please find the reformulated question in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68882097/when-running-script-julia-i-run-run-nf-jl-the-error-following-error-is-disp

Comment: Why have you edited this post into a copy of that one? You really shouldn't do that.

Comment: @F1Krazy What should be the correct procedure?

Comment: You should have just left this Meta post alone. Once a question's been answered, you should never change it into a completely different question, and *especially* not into one that's completely off-topic for Meta *and* has already been asked in a place where it *is* on-topic. I seriously don't understand why you did that.

Comment: @F1Krazy I did it because I wanted to change the questions for a more useful question because it was already tagged as closed and tagged as duplicated. So there where a message suggesting to change it. 

Btw, how can I avoid more negative points?

Answer (score 3):

The gist you should be getting from comments is that you can ask *any* programming question on this site, as long as it is on-topic and well-written, but that is saying a lot because often it is not easy to write a well-received question on this site.

So, to sum:

- Julia programming questions *may* be on-topic on this site, and there is nothing per se against these types of questions
- But only if the questions satisfy the rules of question quality and site appropriateness that all questions must satisfy and as outlined in the [help site](https://stackoverflow.com/help) links